# Get instances of rows in excel for a particular group

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have dataset containing list of checks numbers.

| Check |
| --- |
| 111 |
| 111 |
| 111 |
| 222 |
| 222 |

I am trying to have a new column in my dataset which would give me 1st, 2nd, ....nth instance for every check. The output would like something as below,

| Check | Instance |
| --- | --- |
| 111 | 1 |
| 111 | 2 |
| 111 | 3 |
| 222 | 1 |
| 222 | 2 |

Comment: its called =COUNTIF(A$2:A2,A2) rolling counts

Answer (score 1):

To create a rolling count for a specific instance that appears in a range of cells, you can use the COUNTIF function with an expanding range.

```
=COUNTIF(A$2:A2,A2)
```

[image]